# System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer doesn't serialize properties from derived classes

Tags: .net-core

I can't have System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer serializing properties from derived classes. Newtonsoft has no issues doing the job.

```cs
namespace TestJson
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClass = new NewClass2
            {
                Value1 = "qsd",
                ShouldBeSerialized = "why am I not serialized?"
            };

            // as expected, getting {"ShouldBeSerialized":"why am not serialized?","Value1":"qsd"}
            var textJsonSerializedFromTop = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<NewClass2>(myClass);

            // expecting {"ShouldBeSerialized":"why am not serialized?","Value1":"qsd"}
            // but getting {"Value1":"qsd"}
            var textJsonSerializedFromBase = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<ClassBase>(myClass);

            // as expected, getting {"ShouldBeSerialized":"why am not serialized?","Value1":"qsd"}
            var newtonSoftSerializedFromBase = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass);
        }
    }
    public class ClassBase
    {
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class NewClass2 : ClassBase
    {
        public string ShouldBeSerialized { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the previous example to show the actual issue, the solution is straight forward, but in the following one, I have no clue how to manage by not using newtonsoft:

```cs
namespace TestJson
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var toSerialize =
                new[] {
                    new ClassBase
                    {
                        Value1 = "aze"
                    },
                    new NewClass2
                    {
                        Value1="qsd",
                        ShouldBeSerialized="why am I not serialized?"
                    }
                 };
            var textJsonSerialized = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(toSerialize);
            // expecting [{"Value1":"aze"},{"ShouldBeSerialized":"why am not serialized?","Value1":"qsd"}]
            // but getting [{"Value1":"aze"},{"Value1":"qsd"}]
            Console.WriteLine(textJsonSerialized);

            var newtonSoftSerialized =  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSerialize);
            // as expected getting [{"Value1":"aze"},{"ShouldBeSerialized":"why am not serialized?","Value1":"qsd"}]

            Console.WriteLine(newtonSoftSerialized);
        }
    }
    public class ClassBase
    {
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class NewClass2 : ClassBase
    {
        public string ShouldBeSerialized { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the non-generic version and pass in the actual type, `.Serialize(toSerialize, toSerialize.GetType())`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That is not really a practical solution though. For example if you want to serialize a list of different types all inheriting the same interface. Only the interface properties will be included. Or even worse, if the interface itself inherits an interface, those properties will not be included.

Comment: I completely agree, but unfortunately I don't think you have any other options right now. There are many shortcomings with the built-in json (de)serializer right now and unfortunately it looks like you either have to live with them, or stop using the built-in code and use json.net instead.

Comment: Let me rephrase that, if you have 2 options, and one is impossible, it doesn't matter how impractical the other one is, it's all you have left. Here, though, you have a third option, and that is to not use the built in json classes. You lose some speed, perhaps, but you gain sanity and usability.

Comment: Using interface is also not working. No wonder newtonsoft got 2 billion download.